# Regex, match the last pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

How can you match the last occurrence of a regex pattern?

For example, how can I match [XXX] in:

```
data[X][XX][XXX]
```

Where X, XX, XXX could be assigned randomly.

I already tried to use a negative lookahead

```
\[.*?\](?!.*?\[.*?\])
```

But the first [ with the last ] will be matched what would not give the correct result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why you get such a result is that the `.` matches a `[` and `]` and any other char other than line break chars. You may replace the lazy dot with a negated character class `[^][]`:

```
\[[^][]*\](?!.*?\[[^][]*\])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EWVifZ/1)

Depending on the regex flavor, you may need to escape `[` and `]` in the character class (in JS, `]` must be escaped (`[^\][]`) and in Java/ICU you need to escape both (`[^\]\[]`)).

Comment: Another solution will be handy in case you can have `]` inside `[...]`: [`\[[^[]*\](?!.*?\[[^[]*\])`](https://regex101.com/r/EWVifZ/2). Also, if you have a multiline input, you should replace `.*?` with `[\s\S]*?`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for simplicity:

```
.*(\[.*\])
```

It will match upto the last occurance but will capture the last occurrence of `[anything]` in group 1 and won't have to look ahead

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/ZRuf4e/2)

Comment: I would prefer this pattern to mine under one condition: the input string is known to be short. With longer inputs with arbitrary locations of the last `[...]`, the first `.*` might cause performance issues.